# Creating a table with a compound primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, clustered-index

Ok I want to create a table

```
TABLE log_table
email nvarchar(255)
,salesrep nvarchar(20)
,blastid int
,timestamp datetime
```

Now the default value for the `timestamp` would be the datetime of when the record is inserted and I want the primary key to be on `email` and `blastid`.

I know you can do it with clustered indexes but I am not sure on the syntax on how to make that happen. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: thanks everyone all of these answers are good so I am going to give everyone an upvote but im selecting the most detailed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.log_table
(
    email nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    salesrep nvarchar(2) NULL,
    blastid int NOT NULL,
    timestamp datetime NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.log_table ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_log_table_timestamp DEFAULT GetDate() FOR timestamp

ALTER TABLE dbo.log_table ADD CONSTRAINT
PK_log_table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    email,
    blastid
)
GO
```

If you are using the create table GUI, you can use control while clicking columns to set as primary keys.

Comment: As I commented on another answer, you are better off using DATETIME2 in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I used the sysdate as the default

Answer (score 2):

```
CONSTRAINT PK_LOG_TBL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (email ASC, email ASC)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE log_table (
    email NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    salesrep NVARCHAR(255),
    blastid INT,
    [timestamp] DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (email, blastid)
)`

I believe the timestamp default would be accomplished with 'GETDATE()' on insert.

Comment: As I added in edit, you would just use 'GETDATE()' when inserting. I do not believe you can have a function be a default value.

Comment: As he is useing SQL Server 2008 MS now recommend using DATETIME2 for all new work as it has better precision. To fill it in use SYSDATETIME() as the dafault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a composite primary key. the syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE log_table
(
    email nvarchar(255),
    salesrep nvarchar(20),
    blastid int,
    timestamp datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (email, blastid)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something else rather than "timestamp" - that is a sql server data type.

```
    create table log_table
    (
    email nvarchar(255) not null
    ,salesrep nvarchar(20)
    ,blastid int not null
    ,timestamp datetime default getdate())


    ALTER TABLE dbo.log_table ADD CONSTRAINT
        PK_log_table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
        email, blastid
        ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```